# How can I take ingame images and videos?

Tags: c#, monogame, ios, visual-studio, macos

I’m using MonoGame and Visual Studio Community on my Mac to develop a game for iOS. I want to take ingame images and videos of the gameplay while the game is running on an iPhone/iPad. Afterwards, I want to use these images and videos for promotional reasons on my website or on facebook.

Is it necessary to install third party software or can I take images and videos in Visual Studio Community without installing additional software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac, you can use Shift-Command (⌘)-3 to take a screenshot, and QuickTime to record the current screen or a portion of it. You're not installing additional software, since they're included in the OS, and you aren't adding unnecessary libraries for screen recording to your game.

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I found out how to make a gameplay video when the app is installed on my iPhone: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-previews/

Answer (score 0):

Or use **ReplayKit**

Overview
Using the ReplayKit framework, users can record video from the screen, and audio from the app and microphone. They can then share their recordings with other users through email, messages, and social media

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit